# measurable functions in product measure space

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a nonnegative function defined on a measurable subset E of R. Show that f is measurable if the region {(x, y) : x ∈ E, f(x) ≥ y} is a measurable subset of R2

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{(x,y) | x \in E, f(x) \ge y \} \cap \{ (x,y) | y \ge 0 \}$, and note that $S$ is measurable.

Then the function $(x,y) \mapsto 1_S(x,y)$ is measurable.
Fubini Tonelli tells us that the function $x \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_S(x,y) dy$ is measurable. Since
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_S(x,y) dy = f(x) $, we see that $f$ is measurable.